Vuejs Test with Vitest fails when I use mock
I am implementing unit tests for my application, but when I try to mock a library that I imported into one of my components, the unit test fails with the following message.
Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. If you are using JSX, make sure to name the file with the .jsx or .tsx extension.
Image
The unit test works correctly but using vi.mock generates that message.
I give a simple example of what generates the error, since the vitest documentation does it almost the same
Component.

Path:
//Scripts/Controllers/sum.js

export function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b
}


Path:
//Scripts/Test/sum.test.js

import { expect, test, vi } from 'vitest'
import { sum } from '../Controllers/sum'

vi.mock('../Controllers/sum');

describe("Test Sum", () =>
{
    it('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () =>
    {
        expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3)
    });
});


//vite.config.js

import { defineConfig } from "vitest/config";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    //add test to vite config
    test: {
        include: [
            'Tests/sum.test.js',
        ],
        resolve: {
            extensions: [
                '.js',
                '.jsx'
            ]
        },
        globals: true,
        environment: 'jsdom',
        coverage: {
            provider: 'istanbul',
            reporter: ['text', 'json', 'html'],
        },
    },
});

I don't know if in the vite.config.js file I should configure the file transformation by js and jsx extension, but I can't find how to do it.
I am not using the vuejs cli, since due to the architecture of my application I had to use Vuejs with cdn.

It looks ok. I don't see why it would cause this error. Please, provide a way to reproduce - a repo, stackbitz, etc. Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551
